# How to get all element by class in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have tried this way:

```js
let elements = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.class-block-list-item');

elements.forEach((element) => {
  console.log(element);
});
```

It returns me only one HTML element, not array

Comment: change querySelector to querySelectorAll

Comment: And how to set style for each in loop?

Comment: in your css file add .class-block-list-item{Your css style}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `querySelector` function only retrieves the first ocurrence of the selection. If you want to get all of them you need to use `querySelectorAll` as shown below:

```
let elements = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".class-block-list-item");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's what you need.

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("class-block-list-item");
```

Comment: There are some differences between `querySelector<All>()` and `getElementsBy` which can lead to bugs. It would be probably better to just change `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll` as it will more likely prevent some side effects

Comment: I think that you're on mistake. The differences between queryselector and getElemensByClass is that querySelector will return a static collection, while getElementsByClassName returns a live collection. The usage of each one depends what you need for, no for bugs!

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can do something like `document.querySelector("#wrap").querySelectorAll("div")` but i remember having problems with `document.getElementById("wrap").getElementsByTagName("div")` for example. I might be mistaken though... as it returns different type of element, i think you don't have the same methods available. I can't verify right now but that pissed me as getElements method are quite faster than querySelector